# Please explain how to derive the PGF of a 6 sided dice

Tags: statistics

I understand the PGF is
$$ P(s) = \frac{s}{6} \frac{1-s^6}{1-s} $$
Can someone explain all the steps to get there

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please update your post with your attempt at thinking through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $p(1)=...=p(6)=\frac16$, $p(0)=0$ and for $k>6$, $p(k)=0$

The PGF is

$G(s)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} p(k) s^k=\sum_{k=1}^{6} p(k) s^k$

So $G(s)=\frac16 \sum_{k=1}^{6} s^k$

We recognize a geometric sum:

$G(s)=\frac{s}{6} \frac{1-s^6}{1-s}$

Comment: Thanks. didn't realize it was a geometric sum

Answer (score 0):

We want

$$f(x)=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^6.$$

By long division we can prove that

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$

If we multiply the above expression by $1-x^7$ we are going to see a pattern where all the $x^n$ exponents will cancel out after $x^6$:

$$\begin{align}&(1-\color{red}{x^7})+(x-\color{blue}{x^8}) +(x^2-x^9)+\cdots+(\color{red}{x^7}-x^{14})+(\color{blue}{x^8}-x^{15})+\cdots\\[2ex]&=1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^6
\end{align}$$

Now we have to get rid of the $1$ in front by multiplying the series by $x.$ That will require reducing the exponent in the numerator exponent from $1-x^7$ to $1-x^6.$

This leaves us with $x\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}.$ And since the probability of each outcome is $1/6,$ the expression is derived:

$$f(x)=\frac 1 6 \frac{x(1-x^6)}{1-x}$$

Comment: Alternatively, $(1-x)(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^6)=x-x^7$.